# Image not showing in wordpress get_content area

Tags: wordpress, image, themes

This is my custom post type template. Everything is okk but any image is not showing in browser.
I create a single file to make custom post type template.

````
<html lang="en" >
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">

</head>
<body>
        <fieldset>
            <?php
              if (have_posts()) :
                while (have_posts()) : the_post() ;
            ?>
            <legend><?php the_title(); ?></legend>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <div>
                        <?php the_content(); ?>
                        <?php
                        foreach($posts as $post) {
                        ?>
                        <?php
                        }
                        ?>
                    </div>
                    <?php
                      endwhile;
                      else :
                        echo 'Nothing Found';
                      endif;
                    ?>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </fieldset>
</body>
</html>```
````

Comment: What does it show when you inspect element on where the image is supposed to be?

Comment: It shows look like this https://prnt.sc/qdaar3 and https://prnt.sc/qdaakm

Answer (score 0):

Please use

```
echo get_the_post_thumbnail();
```

OR

```
$image = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ) );
echo $image[0];
```